# TeX (not LaTeX)? Includgraphics? Tree packages

Tags: graphics, plain-tex

How do I actually include graphics into a TeX document . There is nothing like `\includegraphics{}`.

Additionally how do I produce graphics in TeX, are there any tree packages or some for of that?

Comment: Welcome! I've changed the tags: I'm assuming you are using the plain TeX format and don't really mean `tex-core`. Also, there's nothing to suggest this is engine specific, is there? (Not as sure about that, though.)

Answer (score 9):

See the file `TDS:tex/plain/graphics-pln/graphicx.tex` that includes the LaTeX `graphicx` package in plain TeX with the help of `miniltx.tex` that defines the necessary parts of LaTeX for plain TeX:

```
% Plain TeX interface to graphicx package.
% David Carlisle

\input miniltx

\def\Gin@driver{dvips.def}
\input graphicx.sty

\resetatcatcode
```

The driver is not declared by option, but by the driver file name.
The version and example for `pdftex` would be:

```
\input miniltx
\def\Gin@driver{pdftex.def}
\input graphicx.sty
\resetatcatcode

\includegraphics{example-image}
\bye
```

### Second question

For example, [pgf/TikZ](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgf) also works with plain TeX.